# LMMS maxes CPU and plays no sound

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, lmms

So I start LMMS normally, but whenever I hit <kbd>Play</kbd> it plays no sound and it's thread uses up the entire CPU. That plus the timing appears to move twice the speed of normal time.

My audio output is set to ALSA, and I know that it produces sound using PulseAudio.

Why can't I use ALSA? LMMS recommends against it for "Bad Latency."

Answer (score 1):

What's happening in this case is that PulseAudio locks the ALSA Backend that LMMS tries repeatedly to access (causing the high CPU) and since Pulse has it locked, LMMS can't send audio through.

You can easily disable PulseAudio while using LMMS by launching LMMS with the command [`pasuspender`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/pasuspender.1.html)`lmms`.

That, or you could just stick to using Pulse as your output, and [applying some latency lowering tips](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudioPreparation).

Answer (score 1):

I *highly* suggest using JACK instead for best performance. Using ALSA my computer will lock up when playing one of the demos. When I have Jack configured properly everything works flawlessly.